# Standalone python script - Qgis - QgsVectorLayer points to wrong feature class in gpkg

Tags: pyqgis, layers, geopackage

GPKG file has multiple featureclasses in it. I create a layer to a specific featureclass using QgsVectorLayer but it always points to the first FC in the gpkg file.

This is a stand alone python script, not the console under the GUI.

```
output_gpkg = r'W:\srm\wml\Workarea\mamcgirr\Q_universal_overlap_tool\work\qscript_outputs\one_status_common_datasets_debug_version_dqu_shape_2.gpkg |layername = Legal_OGMA'

fc_input_layer = QgsVectorLayer(output_gpkg, 'test', 'ogr')

if not fc_input_layer.isValid():
    print("layer invalid.")
else:
    print("layer valid.")

for field in fc_input_layer.fields():
    print(field.name(), field.typeName())
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove space in your `output_gpkg`.You can try typing another layer name and you will see how the first one loads as well.
for example :

```
output_gpkg = r'W:\srm\wml\Workarea\mamcgirr\Q_universal_overlap_tool\work\qscript_outputs\one_status_common_datasets_debug_version_dqu_shape_2.gpkg |layername = INVENT'
```

to load the correct layer you must remove all spaces leaving it so:

```
output_gpkg = r'W:\srm\wml\Workarea\mamcgirr\Q_universal_overlap_tool\work\qscript_outputs\one_status_common_datasets_debug_version_dqu_shape_2.gpkg|layername=Legal_OGMA'
```

Comment: Excellent. Removing the spaces fixed it. Thanks very much. It was driving me crazy.

Comment: Hey Mark, welcome to GIS SE. This does not really answer the question. Instead, you should upvote the question and accept it if it solved your issue.